# Extracting only field values from Java Avro/JSON

Tags: java, avro, java-11

I have to do "like" "query" on all fields of list of objects.

Basically, on implementation level it would be something
like this:

```
List<MyObj> result = before.stream()
  .filter(obj -> obj.toString()
    .contains(search))           
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Problem is that my objects are avro records, so their toString() might be like this:

```
"{
\"id\": 12345,
\"name\": null,
\"surname": \"John\"
}"
```

So above search would also look among null value fields and field names which is not what I would like.

Is there any Avro/JSON/standard Java function that lets to look through all(or even better, specific) field values?

Something that would let me to write code similar to below one:

```
List<MyObj> result = before.stream()
  .filter(obj -> obj.lookupInAllFields(search))           
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I could write similar function myself, but it seems as not optimal solution if such function already exists

Comment: Do you mean you want to look for your search string only in json `value` fields and not on json `keys`? It seems you need to implement a recursive function to handle nested fields and arrays.

Comment: @MaxG yes, exactly that. So there's no such function? OK, it's not a problem to write it myself. I thought it was already done before, and I don't like reinventing the wheel